# Star Schema - Attributes in Fact Tables

Tags: sql, data-modeling, dimension, star-schema, fact

normally a fact table in a Star Schema contains just foreign keys to the dimension tables and measures. Let's say I have a delivery and I want to store the delivery # and a reference # can I just store the delivery & reference # in the fact table?

It's a key value in my source system but I use IDs as keys in my data warehouse. Right now I have it that way and an attribute like Material# which contains further data obviously in a dimension table but would I have to create dimension table just for the delivery# and reference# ? I don't really see the point of doing that.

I can't find any articles about making such exceptions in a fact table.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, these are called "degenerate dimensions."  You don't need to add a dimension table, it's kind of implied that the dimension is expressed in the source system.